# Is it wrong to have a base interface with only properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, interface

I'm trying to build a flexible structure which can return any type of object (specific for each client REST/WCF integration) and I was wondering what would be the best way to return it.

What I have in mind is to have a base interface, with one property, which would be inherited by the returning types AND I want to make it as generic as possible.

So:

```
public interface IBase
{
   string Id { get;set; }
}

public class ReturnType : IBase
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
   public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public IBase Call()
{
   return (IBase)ServiceCall();
}

public object ServiceCall()
{
   return new ReturnType();
}
```

EDIT:

To give a better idea, here's the current flow I'm working on:

Step 1

```
public ISwitchResponse CompanySwitch(AddSwitchRequest switchRequest)
{
    return GetCalculator(CreditBrokerCalculatorNames.MortgageLoan).Switch<UCISwitchResponse>(switchRequest);
}

private ICreditBrokerOfferCalculationService GetCalculator(CreditBrokerCalculatorNames calculatorName)
{
    return _calculatorResolver.CreateCreditBrokerSwitchCalculator(calculatorName.ToString());
}
```

Step 2

```
public T Switch<T>(AddSwitchRequest request) where T : ISwitchResponse
{
    SwitchRequest switchRequest = _calculatorRepository.AddAndGetSwitchRequest(request.RequestId, request.ServiceOfferId, request.SwitchAnswers, request.HasFullALineAccess, request.IsDecoAssociated);
    var response = (T)_companyIntegratorManager.CommunicateNewSwitch(switchRequest);
    response.HumanId = _calculatorRepository.GetCalculationInstanceHumanId(request.RequestId);
    return response;
}
```

Step 3

```
public object CommunicateNewSwitch(SwitchRequest switchRequest)
{
    var switchAnswers = switchRequest.SwitchAdditionalAnswers.ToDictionary(_ => _.PropertyName, _ => _.PropertyValue,
                                    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    Provider provider = switchRequest.ServiceOffer.Provider;
            string serviceName = $"{provider.CommunicatorPrefix.Value}{provider.Calculator.Name}";

    ICompanyService service = GetCreditCompanyServiceInstance(serviceName);

    try
    {
       var switchResponse = service.Switch(switchAnswers);
       return switchResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"CommunicateNewSwitch - ERROR! UCI MakeSwitch {switchRequest.CalculationInstanceId} threw exception.", ex);
        throw new Exception($"CommunicateNewSwitch - ERROR! UCI MakeSwitch {switchRequest.CalculationInstanceId} threw exception.", ex);
    }
}
```

Step 4

```
public object Switch(Dictionary<string, string> answers)
{
   var factory = new DictionaryAdapterFactory();
   var request = factory.GetAdapter<IUCISwitchRequest>(answers);

   using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_url) })
   {
      try
      {
         string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
         string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_username}:{_pwd}"));
         var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", auth);

         HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("prequalificar", stringContent).Result;

         UCISwitchResponse result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UCISwitchResponse>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

         return result;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         _logger.Error($"Switch - ERROR! UCI Switch threw exception.", ex);
         throw new Exception($"MakeSwitch - ERROR! UCI MakeSwitch threw exception.", ex);
      }
   }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface ISwitchResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    string HumanId { get; set; }
}
```

Class

```
public class UCISwitchResponse : ISwitchResponse
{
    public string HumanId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Resultado")]
    public string Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LeadID")]
    public string LeadId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Pdf")]
    public string PdfUrl { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Motivo")]
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Mensagem")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Erros")]
    public List<Errors> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Errors
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Codigo")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Descricao")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My questions are: Is it wrong to do that? Am I better off using an abstract class? If not, what are the best option to achieve this?

Comment: *I want to make it as generic as possible* then why don't you use generics?

Comment: @Selvin: Because the term "generic" doesn't always mean the same as "generics in C#". I'd read this as "I want to make it as general purpose as possible".

Comment: It is not wrong, no (I am not saying it is the **best** solution, but it certainly isn't wrong). You may want to consider having _only_ getters in the interface (not setters), but I don't have enough context to know whether that makes sense for you or not.

Comment: @Selvin, I was using generics, but changed it cause I didn't want to specify a type.

Comment: @JonSkeet, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: @mjwills, thanks for pointing these details out. What would be a better solution though? What I want is to call a WCF service, that will communicate with other services (WCF or REST), and return a common type, which I intend to cast to a specific type later, in the website part that receives this interface.

Comment: *I was using generics, but changed it cause I didn't want to specify a type.* , *intend to cast to a specific type later,* ... still the question is why didn't you use generics  ...

Comment: @Selvin, I didn't want to specify a type at the service end, but at the website, when getting the response interface. Sorry, but are you here to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to call a WCF service, that will communicate with other services (WCF or REST), and return a common type, which I intend to cast to a specific type later, in the website part that receives this interface.
>
> ```
> public IBase Call()
> {
>    return (IBase)ServiceCall();
> }
>
> public object ServiceCall()
> {
>    return new ReturnType();
> }
> ```
>
> Is it wrong to do that?

Yes.

It's not wrong to have an interface that exists of just one or a few properties, but that's only *usable* if the caller can do whatever it needs to do with those properties.

When you declare a method to return an interface, you're providing a contract, meaning callers shouldn't care about what actual type gets returned. When a method returns an `ICollection<string>`, the caller shouldn't cast the result to a list, or array, or collection, or whatever, because that's in no way guaranteed. What's guaranteed, is that *any* type implementing said interface could be returned, and that should be enough for the caller.

I'm sure you have your reasons for doing this, like abstraction (hiding the dirty web service parts) or reducing code duplication, but this isn't the way.

If your caller needs a `Foo`, then provide them with a method that returns a `Foo`. Even if that `Foo` happens to implement `IBase`, because the caller can't do anything with an `IBase` and they'll have to cast it to a `Foo` anyway, and that'll break as soon as someone starts returning a `Bar`. It'll compile and run just find as long as `Bar : IBase`, but it'll blow up at the cast.

So what you're probably after, is generics, as @vhr says:

```
    var result = svc1.Call<ReturnType1>();
```

And now `result` is of the type the calling code can do something with.

Comment: I was using generics for that, but i thought it would be a good idea not to specify a type when calling my WCF service. I have updated the questions with the actual flow that i'm working. And thanks for the response!!

Comment: _"i thought it would be a good idea not to specify a type when calling my WCF service"_ - but then you'll have to cast the response to ... that type you didn't want to specify.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to have to cast on the WCF(step 1).

Comment: But it'll always be a `UCISwitchResponse`, so it makes no sense to return an interface there. Definitely not to return `object`.

Comment: That's the problem. This method will always return the same. If I need a new method returning another type, i'll have to create another one, instead of using the same returning a more general type.

Comment: And that's why you need generics all the way down. The culprit is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UCISwitchResponse>()` which I think I saw somewhere in your screenshots. Replace that with `TResponse` and you're done. Also, add the code to your question instead of the screenshots.

Answer (score -2):

It is not wrong and even Microsoft is using it as an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)

I would also consider usage of generics in your method (I konw it is not the same as generic). It could look like this:

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IService
{
    IBase Call<T>() where T : class, IBase;
}

public class ReturnType1 : IBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }

    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public class Service1 : IService
{
    public ReturnType1 ReturnType { get; set; }

    IBase IService.Call<T>()
    {
        return new ReturnType1();
    }
}

public class ClientApp
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IService svc1 = new Service1();
        IBase result = svc1.Call<ReturnType1>();

        Console.WriteLine(result.GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills is right. [I was actually using generics](https://i.imgur.com/HVlTkLS.png) before, but I really didn't know if it was the best solution, so I changed it to be less specific on the service side and more at the website side.

Comment: What's the point of casting to `T` if the return type is still `IBase`?

Comment: I have updated my question with some links of the steps I was taking. Those are the steps from my WCF service, not from the website. The website is going to call this service and get a object as response, which could be any object since every client service returns it's own type.